# LINQ to Objects - Grandparent, Parent, Child Relationship

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects

I am new to LINQ and I have been able to write a few simple statements. But now I have a more complicated situation which I cannot figure out.

Basically, I am trying to write a LINQ to Objects statement where the relationship is a grandparent, parent, child relationship. (You could also call it a Master Detail relationship.)

In Legacy code here is a simplified version what I am trying to accomplish.

```
        Dim coverages As New List(Of Coverage)
        Dim coverage As Coverage 

        For Each rl In oClaimsPolicy.RiskLocations 

            coverage = New Coverage
            coverage.Level = "Location"

            'Get rl detail detail
            coverages.Add(coverage) 

            For Each ri In rl.RiskItems 

                coverage = New Coverage
                coverage.Level = "Item"

                'Get ri detail
                coverages.Add(coverage) 

                For Each rc In ri.RiskCoverages 

                    coverage = New Coverage
                    coverage.Level = "Coverage"

                    'Get rc detail here
                    coverages.Add(coverage) 

                Next 

            Next 

        Next
```

If is it not clear one `Location` can have many `Items` and one `Item` can have many `Coverages`.  I basically want to list the items and show the relationship between grandparent (Location),  parent (Item) and child (Coverage).

### **Update:**

Here is what I came up with:

```
Dim coverages = oClaimsPolicy.RiskLocations. _
                  SelectMany(Function(rl) rl.RiskItems. _
                  SelectMany(Function(ri) ri.RiskCoverages. _
                  Select(Function(rc) New Coverage With {.Level = "Coverage"})))
```

However, this just listed out all of the children (Coverages).

This is the result I am looking for:

```
Location
    Item 
       Coverage 
    Item 
       Coverage 
       Coverage 
Location 
    Item 
       Coverage
```

So, the data is Grouped By Location and Item.

Another way to look at it is a ListView or a Report.  Where the Grouping is done by Location and Item.

An example is shown below

```
Location
    Item
        Coverage
    Item
        Coverage
        Coverage
Location
    Item
        Coverage
```

Is this clear?

Comment: What have you tried so far, please post code. And how has it not delivered on your requirement (show desired and actual output).

Comment: Lazarus, 

I updated the entry per your request.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Your original query didn't compile when I went to test it. Here's a version that does:

```
Dim coverages = _
    From rl In oClaimsPolicy.RiskLocations _
    From ri in rl.RiskItems _
    From rc in ri.RiskCoverages _
    Select New Coverage With {.Level = "Coverage"}
```

Now, to get the kind of results that you want try doing this:

```
dim create As Func(Of String, IEnumerable(Of Coverage)) = _
    Function (level) New Coverage() _
        { New Coverage With { .Level = level } }

Dim coverages = _
    From rl In oClaimsPolicy.RiskLocations _
    From cl In create("Location").Concat( _
            From ri In rl.RiskItems _
            From ci In create("  Item").Concat( _
                    From rc In ri.RiskCoverages _
                    From cc In create("    Coverage") _
                    Select cc) _
            Select ci) _
    Select cl
```

It's a bunch of nested `SelectMany` & `Concat` expressions and it produces a list of `Coverage` objects like this:

```
Location
  Item
    Coverage
Location
  Item
    Coverage
  Item
    Coverage
```

Is this what you're after?